# how can i write mql5 code that close the positions profits are equal to 0 and generate any lossses?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

Can anyone advice me on writing code that when the profit is equal to 0 close the position? I wrote it by myself but it didn't work. I want to write code that generates no losses and it is how it works:
i want to enter a position in a condition and close it if my close condition is called or my positions profits are 0 because i want to generate no loss at all i don't allow my positions getting loss and rapidly close them when they are 0.

i try this but it just generates continuously generates loss.

```
#include <Trade\Trade.mqh>


CTrade trade;


void OnTick()
{
    // Check if there is an open buy position
    bool hasOpenBuyPosition = CheckOpenBuyPosition();
    double Ask = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK), _Digits);

    // Get the current symbol price
    double currentPrice = SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_ASK);

    // Get the open price of the buy position
    MqlRates PriceInformation[];
    ArraySetAsSeries(PriceInformation, true);
    double Data=CopyRates(Symbol(), Period(), 0, Bars(Symbol(), Period()), PriceInformation);

    if (PriceInformation[1].close < Ask) {
         
         trade.Buy(0.1);
       }
       
       
   
       CloseZeroProfit();
   }


void CloseZeroProfit()
{
   // Iterate through all open positions
   for (int i = 0; i < PositionsTotal(); i--)
   {
      // Select the position by its index
      if (PositionSelectByTicket(PositionGetTicket(i)))
      {
         // Check the position's profitability
         double profit = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PROFIT);
         if (profit <= 0 || profit == 0)
         {
            // Close the position
            trade.PositionClose(PositionGetTicket(i));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code closes positions when profit <=0 .. so there will always be losses (spread, commission).
Where is your takeprofit for an open position?

```
trade.Buy(0.01,_Symbol, 0, 0, ask + 20 * _Point)
```

and change

```
for(int i = 0; i < PositionsTotal(); i--)
```

on this

```
for(int i = 0; i < PositionsTotal(); i++)
```